# Hide a field in layout from Studio SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to hide the status field on the Leads Module in the studio.
I've tried using the following code:

`$dictionary["Lead"]["fields"]["status"] = array(
        "studio" => "hidden",

);`

but the field is still visible on the Editview, Detailview, and Listview layouts of the leads module. I've also tried the following code;

`$dictionary["Lead"]["fields"]["status"]["studio"] = array(
        "editview" => false,

        "detailview" => false,

        "listview" => false,

);`

But still the status field is visible on the layouts?
Are there other ways to hide that field on the studio?
Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?PHP 
$dictionary['Lead']['fields']['status']['studio'] = false; 
?>
```

That certainly works in Sugar 6.5

Answer (score 0):

First of, you'll need to create an extended vardefs for Leads:
custom/Extension/modules/Leads/ext/Vardefs/vardefs.ext.php.

Then fill it with:

```
<?PHP 
$dictionary['Lead']['fields']['status']['studio'] = 'invisible'; 
?>
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried your solution but it does not work. Also, i've tried setting the "invisible" value to an empty array which also does not work.